# Is there a way to check all manual resolved merge conflicts of mercurial?

Tags: javascript, version-control, merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

Simple, as the question says, is there a way to check all manual resolved merge conflicts of the whole repository within mercurial (tortoise-hg)?

It would be awesome if I could track at least merges, where a conflict happened.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "no merge conflicts" is not something which can be answered - or stated unambiguously as it highly depends on the merge algorithm applied when merging automatically. Check `hg help merge-tools` for the available internal algorithms. You can configure your own external merge tools which might work better for you. Can can even configure different merge tools for different file types.

If you choose "always use side A in case of conflicting information", then there simply will not ever be conflicts as it always can be resolved automatically.
Using more sophisticated algorithms, you will get differnt results depending on your choice and they may also differ in what they think they can handle automatically and suggest to you as merge result.

Additionally: whatever algorithm you choose, you always have the option to manually alter the file contents from what is suggested as merge result - and only then you commit your possibly edited merge result. Mercurial has no way of knowing whether you made manual changes, nor does it record what merge algorithm was used.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that if a conflict must be resolved, it saves it somehow this action with maybe the revision number of the merge into a logfile. For manual merging, I use Meld so it is already an external tool. The thing is, I would like to trace the code which was merged manually so I can check twice if everything was merged correctly, especially within a teamup.

Comment: I don't quite get it: what is - to you - the difference between 'manual merge' and automatic(?) merge? Someone [TM] always has to commit the merge. Mercurial stores the two ancestor revisions irrespective of who made the merge and which merge tools he used

Comment: For me, the difference of an automatic merge and a manual merge is: For a 'manual merge' I have to resolve conflicts on my own (like with Meld). It's of a 3-way comparison (old -> result <- new).
For an automatic merge a user does not have to step into the process.In any case the user has to commit in both cases.
Maybe a short example for a conflict: You have a point from which you open two branches. Then you change something on the same place in both branches. Afterwards you want to merge it back to the start point. Mercurial cannot resolve it (automatically).

Comment: Well, but the conflict resolution is done by the merge programme which may be mercurial or - in your case - meld. Automatic merges can even be as wrong as can be manual ones. Consider that you rename a variable in one branch, keep the old name in the other and add an additional line somewhere else where it is used. Thus the automatic merge will work just fine - but the resulting code will be broken.